# Trello - Cards overview page

Tags: trello-cards

Just starting to use Trello with my project group. I'm also using it for personal projects so I might want to use the Cards page for important tasks the most.

We have several lists including ToDo and Completed.
Can I set the cards or lists in a way that only those in the To Do-list or all lists except for the Completed list pop up on the Cards page or would I have to unassign myself from the cards?

Comment: This looks like multiple questions. Can you break individual things out into separate questions (after searching for your question to be sure it hasn't been asked/answered already)?

Comment: It's not, it's a question regarding one thing - the cards overview page.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to unassign yourself from the completed cards since only cards you're assigned to are displayed in the card view.